# Detecting the opening or closing of a details element

Tags: javascript, html

How can I detect when a details element is opened or closed in Javascript? Other than attaching a listener to the click function and checking if the open attribute is set or not.

Comment: Hello please have a look at the current answers and re-evaluate whether the one you have accepted is actually the correct answer.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use the [toggle event](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-details-element:attr-details-open-4):

```js
var details = document.querySelector("details")

details.addEventListener("toggle", function() {
 details.firstChild.textContent = "done"
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<details>
 <summary>toggle event</summary>
</details>
```

Comment: Good to know that the toggle event doesnt seem to bubble (?), and that the 'open' attribute seems to be modified *before* the event fires.

Comment: @commonpike I can confirm that the toggle event does not bubble. As for the open attribute, my tests show that it is modified after the event fires.

Answer (score 7):

To test the current state, without events listeners, we can simply check if the attribute `open` is set:

```js
// Test
onclick = () => {
  console.log(
    !detailElem.hasAttribute("open")
  )
}
```

```html
<details id="detailElem">
  <summary>Some details</summary>
</details>
```

Comment: poor solution. details isn't being opened and closed only by clicks. it can be open/close via focus+enter/space and programmatically with `setAttribute()`.

Comment: @ATP If it's a poor solution, what is the proper solution?

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery you can catch the event using `.on('toggle')` like this:

```
$('#detail-id').on('toggle', function() {
   //code
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
/* Handle for details */
const detailsElements = document.querySelectorAll("details");

function handleClickOnDetails() {
  // close all details
  let detailsOpened = document.querySelectorAll("details[open]");

  for (const item of detailsOpened) {
    // keep open only details clicked
    if (this != item) {
      item.removeAttribute("open");
    }
  }
}

detailsElements.forEach(function (item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", handleClickOnDetails);
});
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Some details 1</summary>
  <p>More info about the details.</p>
</details>

<details>
  <summary>Some details2 </summary>
  <p>More info about the details.</p>
</details>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("details").on("click", function () {
  $("details[open]").not(this).removeAttr("open");
});
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,400i,700";*{position:relative;margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;font-family:Montserrat,sans-serif}:focus{outline:none}body{background:#e0e0e0;height:100vh}div{width:400px;margin:0 auto;top:50%;transform:translateY(-50%);color:#464646;border:1px solid silver}p,summary{background:#fff}summary{padding:20px;width:400px;font-size:19px;z-index:1;border-bottom:1px solid silver;cursor:pointer}p{width:440px;margin:-2px -20px 0;padding:30px;font-size:15px;line-height:1.5;border:1px solid silver;text-align:justify;z-index:2;box-shadow:0 0 30px -12px #000}details[open] p{animation:det .3s}@keyframes det{0%{opacity:0}100%{opacity:1}}button{float:right;background:#0288d1;border:0;padding:11px;margin:-6px -6px 0 0;color:#fff;border-radius:4px;cursor:pointer}button:hover{background:#01579b}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <details>
        <summary>Standard Room</summary>
        <p>A standard room of a standard size, with a standard number of beds. Comes with the standard number of facilities. The view is of, well the usual. No balcony.</p>
    </details>
    <details>
        <summary>Deluxe Room</summary>
        <p>Like the Standard Room, but better. Comes with a balcony.</p>
    </details>
    <details>
        <summary>Family Suite</summary>
        <p>A suite for families. Twice the size of the standard room, three times the number of beds and four balconies.</p>
    </details>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example component in Vue:

```
<template>
  <details @toggle="toggle" :open="openItem">
    <summary>
      <slot name="summary"/>
    </summary>
    <slot name="content"/>
  </details>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    open: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      openItem: this.open,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle({target}) {
      this.openItem = target.open
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

No need to detect toggles/clicks or use jQuery. Just loop through the array result of document.querySelectorAll("details[open]") for open details elements and document.querySelectorAll("details:not([open])") for closed details elements. (You can also style closed/open details element using those selectors in CSS3.)

Comment: OP asks how you'd detect the event when a details element is being opened, not find which elements are open or closed.

Answer (score -3):

Since this is continuing to be voted down, and I can't remove it since it's the accepted answer, I'll refer to @Daniel Herr's post as a more up-to-date solution.

Old answer:

```
<details id="element">
   <p>Details</p>
</details>

<script>
   var isOpen = ($("#element").attr("open") == "open");

   alert ("Open = " + isOpen);
</script>
```

Comment: I am looking for an event that fires when the state changes from opened to closed or vice-versa.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the onclick event?  You can always try binding on the `DOMAttrModified` event.  In either case, the `details` element is so new and not supported by many browsers so it's hard to say how it'll end up working down the road.

Comment: Well, if I'm using the onclick event than I might as well be using two div's instead of details and summary. It's only two extra lines of jQuery and I don't to worry about cross-browser compatibility. 
I didn't know about the DOMAttrModified, but I don't think it's working in Chrome, and the detail element is not working anywhere else except Chrome :)))